# Access a MySite Blog from a home page webpart

Tags: sharepoint-2010, mysite, spcontext, web-parts

I've been away from SharePoint development for quite a while now, and I'm trying to access the information in a SharePoint 2010 blog (from one of our users, within their "MySite") from a C# webpart which will reside on the homepage of the site.  The idea is to be able to highlight a certain user's latest post on the home page.

Can anyone help me to reference the blog (in dev it is located at http://myServer/my/BillsBlog) from our homepage.  I've tried the following...

- Reference an SPSite giving the URL as a constructor parameter, then get the correct web from there.  This fails. (I'm guessing the blog is a web, rather than a site collection, but am open to being corrected there)
- Get the current context from SPContext.Current, and access the AllWebs collection from there, but this doesn't inculde the /my web.

Once I find the appropriate container (SPSite or SPWeb) I can access the list to pull out the items I need, but I don't know how to get to that point.  In a console App, I have it working by using the method in the first bullet abouve.

I'm really pretty much stuck now, and I simply don't know enough about what I'm looking fro to be able to search Google for answers.  Any help you could give me would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, my mistake.  The webpart project was set up as a sandboxed one, so the approach in bullet 1 wouldn't work.  Changing that switch meant it is now OK and working as per the console app.

Thanks for reading.